# SQL Server stored procedure: Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
DECLARE @occurrences TABLE (Occurrences int)
BEGIN
    SET @occurrences = (SELECT Occurrences FROM [Data])
END
```

Why this is not possible to execute? I want to read into a table all the columns of a given table within my stored procedure so I can update later another table.

Is this fundamentally wrong?

The exact error that SQL Server throws is:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@occurrences"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Table` variables are different than `scalar` variables. So you need

```
DECLARE @occurrences TABLE (Occurrences int)
BEGIN
    insert @occurrences 
    SELECT Occurrences FROM [Data]
END
```

Comment: Of course! If I wasn't declaring a table but just a parameter for a single value I guess my query would have work (as long as it returns just one value) but in this case I need to use INSERT. Thanks a lot!